# Define root in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-configuration

I am trying to make clean url in a website using RewriteRule . But when i call the page from different pages (eg. Header-included in different pages) , it shows 404 - object not found.

I observed that the url treated as different in each page. As per my observation i may need to set a root folder and have to redirect all pages based on that . So that it will redirect to the right destination.

Any information on .htaccess will be helpful

my .htaccess code as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index2.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/songs?$ album.php?ad=$2 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ category.php?ct=$1 [QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/cat?$ /category.php?ct=$2 [QSA,NC]
```

and my directory:

```
localhost
   |
   +mysite
       |
       +mp3
           |
            index2.php
            category.php
            album.php
```

Comment: Can you show the .htaccess file you have now?

Comment: rewrites won't help if your paths/urls are relative.

Comment: I have updated the question with code and directory tree @SuperDJ

Comment: I think that might be the actual problem, Kindly check the code and give an advise on paths @LawrenceCherone